# With boost::msm eUML, if I give attributes_ << to the state machine or state, how do I (re)set them?

Tags: boost-msm

If I add attributes to an event, I know I can then use the event name like a function...

```
BOOST_MSM_EUML_EVENT_WITH_ATTRIBUTES(*someEvent*, *someAttributeList*)

someStateMachine.process_event(
   someEvent (
      valueOfSomeAttribute1, // sets the attribute value here
      valueOfSomeAttribute2))
```

and that inside an action I can this back by writing

```
evt.get_attribute(someAttribute1);  // retrieve the attribute value
```

Now, if I set an attribute for an entire machine, like so:

```
BOOST_MSM_EUML_DECLARE_STATE_MACHINE((transition_table,
                         init_ << initState,
                         Entry_Action, 
                         Exit_Action, 
                         attributes_ << someAttribute1 << someAttribute2,
                         configure_<< someConfigurationStuff ),
                         newStateMachineType)
```

**How do I go about setting a value for someAttribute1?**

Same question for states:

```
BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE(
       (someEntryAction,
        someExitAction,
        attributes_ << someAttribute1,
        configure_<< someConfigurationStuff)
       ,newStateName)
```

**How do I go about setting a value for someAttribute1?**

Finally,

**Is there a way to change the attributes after the object is created?**

For instance, I'd like to have an attribute for the state machine, and in one of my states, remember some piece of information that I can store in the state machine.  (In this case, I want to store a socket.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I go about setting a value for someAttribute1?**
You can:

- change the reference you just got (get_attribute returns a reference): ++evt.get_attribute(someAttribute1).
- use the functors to write the attribute in your table directly. For example, following action is possible: /++fsm_(someAttribute1)

For states, you can do the same. And for state machines, well, ditto.
Again, you can either use the Fsm template parameter in your actions, or the functors (fsm_, event_, etc.)

You can find good example of all in the examples or tests (for example test/CompositeEuml.cpp or test/AnonymousEuml.cpp).

HTH,
Christophe

Comment: Thanks, Christophe.  Actually I discovered that my problem was, I believe, a bug.  I submitted a message to the mailing list about it.  It's very obscure.  I can make it work or not work at will.

Comment: Here's some sample code that shows the problem I'm having:  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22399463/example.zip  I submitted to the mailing list, but it's my first post, and I don't know if I've done everything correctly.  The problem happens when you set an fsm attribute in an an action that is the entry action for the fsm and the fsm is a substate of another fsm, and happens also to be the parent fsm's initial state.